# time data Month doesn't match format specified

Tags: python, datetime

I know this question has already been asked/answered, but I have tried all of the solutions and nothing seems to get rid of the error.

Example of data from my dataframe, column 'Month' :-

Month
2015-09

code I used to convert column 'Month' data into datetime format :-

```
df.Month = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%Y-%m')
```

Error :-

```
ValueError: time data Month doesn't match format specified
```

If I flip the format to (format='%m-%Y') **wrong format I know**

I get the error message:

`time data '2015-09' does not match format '%m-%Y' (match)`

But my original format matched up exactly..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you please provide more information about your code or data?

Comment: I downloaded a csv file from, https://data.police.uk/data/. Forces - Police service of northern ireland. The columns were as follows; Crime ID, Month, Reported by, Falls within, Longitute, Latitude, Location, LSOA code, LSOA name, Crime type, Last outcome category, Context. The data within the Month column for one of the rows was of the format (2015-09). When i tried to to change the data in that column  to datetime format '%Y-%m' I got a - time data does not match format error. Apologies for not being very clear, first time asking a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message says:
`ValueError: time data Month doesn't match format specified`

This error was raised because the `df.Month` contains a string: `Month`, which in fact doesn't match format specified. The data source you commented provided number of csv files, so I assume this might be a concatenating issue, where the headers from next file were not properly handled.

You may want to check your column using `df.Month.value_counts()` to see if it is has anything other than `to_datetime` parse-able strings.